# How to install fancyvrb within mactex?

Tags: fancyvrb

I like to use http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb with http://tug.org/mactex but its not clear to me how to install it within mactex ?

Comment: If you have installed the full MacTeX, then `fancyvrb` is already installed.  Have you tried to use it?

Comment: When you're not sure whether a package is installed, run in your terminal: `tlmgr show package-name`; in this case `tlmgr show fancyvrb`.

Comment: hi alan and claudio thx a lot for the answers and clarifications - sorry for creating a duplicate question // pelle